# Access values and functions from child components

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and want to build a login mask. I have two child components, one contains the input fields and the other one a login button.
I am trying to call a login function when the button is pressed and access the values from the input fields there.

I am not sure whats the correct solution for my problem, I tried using a provider with a model class but, when I run the app and click in the input fields my input field and the login button disappears. I am also open for completely different solutions if they would be better in my case.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final loginFieldController = TextEditingController();
  void login() {
    print(loginFieldController.value);
  }
}

class LoginState extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 15, left: 15, bottom: 380),
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              LoginContentWidget(),
              LoginHeaderWidget(),
              FloatingLoginButton(),
            ])));
  }
}

class LoginHeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Card(
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          elevation: 15,
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 40, right: 40),
                    child: Text(
                      'LOGIN',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.amberAccent,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 45),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class LoginContentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => LoginContentWidgetState();
}

class LoginContentWidgetState extends State<LoginContentWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
      child: Card(
          elevation: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 80, bottom: 70),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  controller: LoginModel().loginFieldController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                      hintText: 'Email'),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                      hintText: 'Password'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class FloatingLoginButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => FloatingLoginButtonState();
}

class FloatingLoginButtonState extends State<FloatingLoginButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        ButtonBar(
          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton.extended(
              label: Text('Login'),
              onPressed: LoginModel().login,
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this, add SingleChildScrollView and move FloatingLoginButton

```
class LoginState extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 15, left: 15, bottom: 380),
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                LoginContentWidget(),
                LoginHeaderWidget(),
               // FloatingLoginButton(),
              ])),
        )
            ,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingLoginButton(),
    )
    ;
  }
}
```

**Edit Question 2** 
declare this outside of all class

```
var loginModel = LoginModel();
```

and change

```
 LoginModel().loginFieldController
```

to

```
 controller: loginModel.loginFieldController,
```

and also change

```
 LoginModel().login
```

to

```
 onPressed: loginModel.login,
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the bug that my fields disapear is now gone and the login button calls the login function, but the values of the input fields are still not output.

Comment: Question 2 has answered. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

In my login function I print the text from the username textfield. I don't get an error but the value is empty.

```
  final loginFieldController = TextEditingController();
  void login() {
    print(loginFieldController.text);
  }

[![Output][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36iLt.png
```